# Junior Developer Burnout

Tags: software-development, startup

Backstory ahead, but the question is: Are there any techniques to overcome job burnout when all techniques I have found don't work? If I quit, I will have to work outside of technology in order to get an immediate job and pay bills, but my body and mind are refusing to cooperate when attempting easy tasks that I am 100 times more capable of solving and have solved in minutes what is now taking me days.

I recently landed my first developer job with a small company (2 other people). I am experiencing burnout and am completely clueless on how to escape it. It has gotten so bad for me that I have coder's block and can't get myself to fix the simplest of issues because I just draw a blank. I have tried everything I have read online about caffeine, more sleep, meditation, playing (and listening to) music, frequent breaks, etc. and I physically cannot lift my hand to write any more code, even though I tried to work on a personal project to see if it was specific to this company. I was shocked to see that I was perfectly able to code a personal project to completion but cannot force myself to write a single line for the company because my mind blanks out and I feel paralyzed. I have never experienced a physical and mental lack of control at this level in my life.

In order to understand the situation, the following is list are some facts specific to my situation, but the question is in regard to overcoming burnout as a Junior developer whose employer has no background in technology. The question should be answerable without the details below but may give insight into my specific situation and shows the reason for my distress.

- 1,000s of lines of cowboy code by a dozen freelancers
- Major service outage by marketing change (almost all customers left)
- I could not troubleshoot properly (being a Jr. Dev in first couple weeks of very first job)
- Had to duct tape parts of the application so that customers could come back while I could redo the 2-year-old code that was deprecated, anyway
- Original developers mistakenly "published" all of their clients' source code to us by virtue of storing their SVN credentials in a plain-text file on the server (hundreds of web apps around the world had full source-code visibility)
- Owner expects major components to be done in days (Again, my first job with no project manager)
- I feel really proud of myself thinking about how much I have done and how I was forced to save the company by myself and pulled through, but I have so much embedded resentment for my employer, especially after the constant criticism and even the comment about him wanting to "punch me in the face" when I tried to refuse to give him a specific day in the future that a major part of the re-write would be finished (remember, no project manager and is my first job)
- I agreed to a 6-month contract at minimum wage just to get into the industry and was under the impression I would have minimal responsibility

Comment: is there a question in here?

Comment: So what is your goal here? Were can we help? (I see you removed some content at the bottom which had the only answerable thing of the post, consider including it back)

Comment: Thank you for the comments... I re-posted this and deleted it from StackOverflow (first question I have asked online) and I tried to delete the question that sounded too much like asking for advice.

Comment: Burnout? Take a break and get some days off.

Comment: I'm curious why you think leaving this job necessarily means not finding another job in tech?  If you're not currently at risk of being fired, just start job hunting while you're still employed there, and then quit after you've found another tech job (and your current contract has expired, natch.  Don't breach your contract.)

Comment: I totally concur, but hope that the contract has notice period.

Comment: Before offering you advice on new ways to tackle your burnout, we would need to know what you've already tried.

Comment: There's no magic tips and tricks.  It's not worth sacrificing your health over, stop working at an unhealthy pace in a toxic environment. Get another job offer and then leave.  If their company fails it's their own responsibility.

Comment: You're not burnt out. You just *really* hate your job. Understandable you've got lead dev responsibilities, no backup, limited experience and minimum wage. Go to your employers and demand that they hire a qualified lead dev or give you the authority and pay appropriate of what they are asking from you. Because right now they are exploiting your desperation and that's why you've subconciously resigned from your job. If they do neither, leave and find a job that matches your abilities.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, you are resentful to the current employer.

Not sure how accessible this solution to you, but seems to me you need a new job.

Comment: Yeah, "cowboy code" alone indicates a lot of hostility.

Comment: Seconding the part where it's probably a matter of you not liking that company. You mentioned a lot of failures on their part, that doesn't speaks well of your company, and it's normal to feel unsatisfied with your job if you perceive your company as being inept. Your mission is not to rescue that company. Unless you have children to maintain, bills to pay and a very urgent need to acquire resumé entries, consider finding another job.

Comment: You are all very correct, but your short answer I think is right to the root: resentment. I bet this probably happens a lot with small companies and start-ups run by non-technical people because he is oblivious to what is possible in a given amount of time and even more so to a junior developer, as far as labels go.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see this as a question but more that you might want advice, so I will give you my advice since I've been in the current situation.

**Search for a new job now**

I took my first job under similar work-related issues.

- I wanted to get in to the coding business.
- Didn't care really to much about the specification about the job. (responsibility, salary etc)
- Went in with the idea that I would be "taken care of" since I was a juniour developer.

Boy I was so wrong in this. The first 6 months of the job was probably the worst anxiety I've ever had in my life. A lot of responsibility was put on me and I was working 8-12 hours everyday. I started to resent my work and my life cause I the only thing I did was to work or thinking about work (Not cause I was interested in work but because my brain was fried).

Thankfully I had a good college friend who pulled me out of it and got me a new job which I truly enjoy. The major thing that changed between this job and my first?

**The Manager**

I still work hard and sometimes over 8 hours, but the responsibility is dispersed between all developers and the manager understands that learning and understanding development takes time. Now I actually like waking up in the morning and traveling to my job. It's exciting.

My advice is look for a new job if you are burned out. A change in the environment is a good thing for your body, and hopefully your brain too.

Comment: I know that this question was put on hold, but these questions REALLY helped validate my feelings and am seeing clearly what I need to do (not that I am saying you guys have been given any responsibility in my decisions, but you guys validated what I was already thinking). @Bojje, your story is exactly what I am seeing. I think the owner just thinks developers are a thing that vomits features if you pressure them enough.